# Add a specific pdf file as an object while generating pdf from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I have some HTML content and I am creating a pdf file using the js pdf library. Along with the content I want to add some pdf files as attachments while generating. Is it possible?

```
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', "a0");
doc.addImage(img, 'png', 150, 25, 900, 100);
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tbl.get(0));
```